# Updating a result in JSON with a dynamic variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to update a value in my JSON.

My JSON result looks like this:

```
results = {"ROWCOUNT":50,"COLUMNS":["PERSONID","NAME"],"DATA":{"PERSONID":["42","43","44"], "NAME":["JOE","TOM","JANE"]}
resultData = results.DATA
```

In the below code I am looping over the result set and attempting to update a value at a position. I believe it is failing because I am not using dynamic variables correctly.

```
var columnName = "NAME";

for(i=0; i < results.ROWCOUNT; i++ ){
 resultData.columnName[i] = "foo" // failing here due to "columnName" being dynamic.
}
```

Comment: This is a JavaScript object, not JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.. You have to use array syntax

```
resultData[columName][i]
```